# My Subquery returned more than 1 value, why?

Tags: sql-server

`Subquery` returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the `subquery` follows`=`,`!=`,`<`, `<=` , `>`, `>=` or when the `subquery` is used as an expression.

```
select 
(SELECT persFName + ' ' + persLName FROM person WHERE persGender = 'M') AS 'Father',
(SELECT persFName + ' ' + persLName FROM person WHERE persGender = 'F') AS 'Mother'
```

is my code, why won't this output

Comment: The error message is pretty clear here. You are using a subquery for your column and that subquery returns more than 1 row. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like....

```
select CASE WHEN persGender = 'M' THEN persFName + ' ' + persLName END AS [Father]
     , CASE WHEN persGender = 'F' THEN persFName + ' ' + persLName END AS [Mother]
FROM person 
WHERE persGender IN ('M', 'F')
```